# How to use a string to invoke a function via and interface

Tags: c#

So here's a simple example put up where I can add and subtract based on a string input. Then instead of calculating on the spot I wanted to create functions so that I can create an interface. The idea: Use the to refer to anything. I want to put and objects in there, with a uniform way of calling the objects (e.g. they all have an interface that exposes a Compute() method) So here are my two pieces of code that I can't get to mesh to complete this.

```
public class Calculator

{
    private Dictionary<string, Func<float,float,float>> _map = new Dictionary<string, Func<float,float,float>>
    {
        { "add", (a,b) => a+b },
        { "subtract", (a,b) => a-b },
        { "multiply", (a,b) => a*b },
        { "divide", (a,b) => a/b },
    };

    public float Compute(float[] numbers, string opCode)
    {
        var operation = _map[opCode];

        float accumulator = numbers[0];
        foreach (var n in numbers.Skip(1))
        {
            accumulator = operation(accumulator, n);    
        }
        return accumulator;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new Calculator();
        Console.WriteLine(c.Compute( new float[] { 2,2 }, "add"));
        Console.WriteLine(c.Compute( new float[] { 3,3 }, "multiply"));
        Console.WriteLine(c.Compute( new float[] {-2,2 }, "subtract"));
        Console.WriteLine(c.Compute( new float[] { 9,3 }, "divide"));
    }
}
```

that demonstrates what outputs I'm looking for. Now creating the interface how do I use it in  a similar fashion to the above framework?

```
public interface ICalculate
{
     int Calculate(int x, int y);
}
public class Add : ICalculate
{
    #region ICalculate Members

    public int Calculate(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Subtract : ICalculate
{
    #region ICalculate Members

    public int Calculate(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an interface?

Comment: This is a simple example of a very complicated problem. Learning C# and this is what I'm trying to practice to do

Comment: All you need to do is put the ICalculates in your dictionary instead of your Funcs isn't it?Then you get the thing out of the dictionary and call Calculate on it...

Comment: @Chris tried that didn't work

Comment: Then show us what you did and describe how it didn't work. It definitely should work.